# How do I get a darker background when using overlay?

Tags: java, android, overlay

I'm using system overlay to display some content. But I want the overlay to dim the background. How do I do it?

**This is how I want it:**

[image]

**This is how I get:**

[image]

Here is my code to set the overlay:

```
overlay = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_popup_dictionary, null);

final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;        
params.x = 0;
params.y = 100;

windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager.addView(overlay, params);
```

Comment: You can create your own overlay with addView with a view that has alpha < 1

Comment: @AntonioVlasic I thought there was some flag that needed to be set. Because when I use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND` it just blackens out the background.

Comment: You can do this by setting the background behind the view to a dark transparent color. Make a view that expands the whole screen and set the background to a dark transparent color such as #99000000, then put the view you want inside that view for it to show the way you want it.

Comment: @NigelBrown That works. Thanks. But I also want it to dismiss the overlay on touching the background.

Comment: @RandomyzeEverything You could set a click listener on the view with the background and when it is clicked just set the visibility of the views to layout.setVisibilty(View.GONE);

Comment: @NigelBrown Click listener is not working on the overlay.

Comment: it should work are you sure you implemented the listener correctly?

Comment: @NigelBrown Yeah. I've implemented it correctly. I can change some attributes programmatically, so it has binded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would make this a `DialogFragment` with this code executed `onStart`; this way you can customize transparency of your dialog

```
dialog.window.apply {
    attributes.apply {
        dimAmount = 0.50f
        flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND
    }

    setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(0))
    setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nigel Brown's answer could work properly.

**1:** create a shape (to get full screen) with a dark color and low opacity.
**2:** create a new layout or frame, put that shape you created as background 
**3:** at the top of this new almost transparent layout, put your layout that will overlay whatever you wanted 
**4:** set a click listener in the background, something like `yourLayout.setVisibilty(View.GONE)` to dismiss the overlay

Hope it works!